# Async await not working with image.onload

Tags: async-await, angular-promise, angular9

I have below async function in Angular 9. I am not very clear with Async await. Problem is op is assigned undefined as dataURI is not evaluated yet. Obviously I am using await async wrong. Pls help

```
async abc(img, datas, wantedWidth, wantedHeight, dataURI) {
  img.onload = await function () {
   var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
   var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
   canvas.width = wantedWidth;
   canvas.height = wantedHeight;
   ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, wantedWidth, wantedHeight);
   dataURI = canvas.toDataURL();
   console.log(dataURI);
 };

img.src = datas;
this.op = dataURI

}
```

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve here. You should not `await` a function literal. I recommend you work through a little async/await tutorial to learn the basics. You will easily find one if you look for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access `dataURI` only then why don't you use it inside image.load function only? like this:

```
abc(img, datas, wantedWidth, wantedHeight, dataURI) {
  img.onload = function () {
   var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
   var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
   canvas.width = wantedWidth;
   canvas.height = wantedHeight;
   ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, wantedWidth, wantedHeight);
   dataURI = canvas.toDataURL();
   console.log(dataURI);

   img.src = datas;
   this.op = dataURI
 };
}
```

or else you can create a separate function for image.load that will return promise, and in promise you can return the value that you want to use, and you can apply await to that promise function